# How to filter a ManyToMany field from django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model named `Universities` in which there is a ManyToMany field named `bookmarks` associated with `User` model. In template file, I have looped through all the universities `{% for university in universities %}` and I am trying to show a bookmark icon based on the logged in user has bookmarked that specific university or not. However, it seems like I can not filter the query in template directly. How do I do that?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't name your models with plural names. "universities" should be "university" because every instance of the model represents a single university.
2. You can access one to many and many to many relationships in the templates. How you do that depends if you have assigned a `related_name` to the relationship.

Let me show you an example:

```
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(Bookmark, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="universities")
```

Then you pass a list of all university models to the template:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = { 'universities' : University.objects.all() }
        return render(request, "mytemplate.html", context)
```

And finally you access all that you need from the template. This part is slightly tricky but not too much.

```
{% for university in universities %}
    {% for bookmark in university.bookmarks.all %}
        {{ bookmark }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you were to instead pass to the template a list of Bookmark instances, then you would have used the `related_name` stated in our example.
So like this:

```
{% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
    {% for university in bookmark.universities.all %}
        {{ university }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you didn't specify a `related_name`, then you can access the same data using the `_set` convention:

```
{% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
    {% for university in bookmark.university_set.all %}
        {{ university }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```